# How to manage relations in RESTful API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, rest

I am learning REST architecture by creating a RESTful service for 'Issues Tracking Application'. Now as many of you know that an ITA has users, projects, issues and comments.

The relations are as follows:

- Projects has issues, these issues are also managed by a certain user.
- Issues has comments, which in turn are also managed (lets say posted) by a certain user
- Projects are also managed by a user.

I am stuck on the decision to structure the routes. I have write some routes in a text file, which I am posting here. Please have a look and suggest the improvements and identify the mistakes.

```
    Models:
  - User
  - Project
  - Issue
  - Comment

1. User
  > Immediate Requirement
    GET       api/users/                /* Authenticate, and then return list of all users */
    GET       api/users/:id             /* Authenticate, and return a particular user */
    POST      api/users/                /* Create a new user */
    PUT       api/users/:id             /* Authenticate, and update a particular user */
  > Add-on Requirement
    GET       api/users/:id/projects/   /* Authenticate, and return list of projects of particular user */
  > Never Mind Requirement
    DELETE    api/users/                /* Authenticate, and delete all users */
    DELETE    api/users/:id             /* Authenticate, and delete a particular user */

2. Project
  > Immediate Requirement
    GET       api/projects/             /* Authenticate, and then return list of all projects */
    GET       api/projects/:id          /* Authenticate, and return a particular project */
    POST      api/projects/             /* Authenticate, and create a new project */
    PUT       api/projects/:id          /* Authenticate, and update a particular project */
  > Add-on Requirement
    GET       api/projects/:id/issues   /* Authenticate, and return a list of issues of particular project */
    POST      api/projects/:id/issues   /* Authenticate, and create new issue for particular project */
    DELETE    api/projects/:id/issues   /* Authenticate, and delete all issues of particular project */
  > Never Mind Requirement
    DELETE    api/projects/             /* Authenticate, and delete all projects */
    DELETE    api/projects/:id          /* Authenticate, and delete a particular project */

3. Issue
  > Immediate Requirement
    GET       api/issues/               /* Authenticate, and then return list of all issues */
    GET       api/issues/:id            /* Authenticate, and return a particular issue */
    PUT       api/issues/:id            /* Authenticate, and update a particular issue */
  > Add-on Requirement
    GET       api/issues/:id/comments   /* Authenticate, and return a list of comments of particular issue */
    POST      api/issues/:id/comments   /* Authenticate, and create a new comment for particular issue */
    DELETE    api/issues/:id/comments   /* Authenticate, and delete all comments of particular issue */
  > Never Mind Requirement
    DELETE    api/issues/               /* Authenticate, and delete all issues */
    DELETE    api/issues/:id            /* Authenticate, and delete a particular issue */

4. Comment
  > Immediate Requirement
    GET       api/comments/             /* Authenticate, and then return list of all comments */
    GET       api/comments/:id          /* Authenticate, and return a particular comment */
    PUT       api/comments/:id          /* Authenticate, and update a particular comment */
  > Never Mind Requirement
    DELETE    api/comments/             /* Authenticate, and delete all comments */
    DELETE    api/comments/:id          /* Authenticate, and delete a particular comment */
```

This post will help a lot of users who are trying to learn REST since relations are the most important and tough thing in this architecture.

Comment: might be a [codereview.se]

Comment: @DanielA.White why would I post a code review here? Isn't there some called learning?

Yes, it's called learning efficient ways.

Comment: It's better to use a singular form when referring to a specific resource, i.e. `api/user/:id`, not "users". Plurals return arrays, singulars return objects.

Comment: @georg I have been reading a lot of tutorials lately and all of them emphasize plurals for resource names.

https://bourgeois.me/rest/

Comment: @ZulfiqarJunejo And Code Review is **all about** giving advice on how to do things better/faster/clearer/more efficiently etc. I don't know if reviewing APIs is On-Topic though.

Comment: Okay my mistake. I will post there. Thanks!

Comment: @ZulfiqarJunejo You should take a look at some of the existing api questions on CR first to get a feel for differences between a good SO question and a good CR question.

Comment: This can only be a good Code Review question if there's code with it. No code = no review.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to comment on the DELETE verb. It is a bad practice to use PUT and DELETE on all the records.

You have used DELETE on all the instances on few of the places. This might be your requirement. In which case there is no alternative but if that is not your absolute requirement it is better to follow the best practice.

Comment: Ohh yes, +1 for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

REST does not put constraints on URI design. So for example by the following URI `api/issues/:id/comments` the only important part is the `:id`. Anything else can be opinion based. This is because by REST you send back links and links will contain the URI or URI template, so your client won't need to reconstruct the URI from scratch. These links have link relations, and the client will use that to check what the link does and how to display it. So the URI is only for internal usage and it is not necessary to document if you follow the [HATEOAS constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). Another reference: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

If you ask me I prefer flat URI structures over hierarchical ones: `api/comments/?issue=:id` and I use to put `/` at the end of collection URIs, but that's just my personal taste.